# What happens if Swift cannot allocate memory?

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management

Many Swift initializers return non-optional objects. This means they cannot be `nil` and are always successful. However, behind the scenes, Swift *has* to allocate the memory *somehow*, and in general memory allocation failure is a possibility. For example, memory returned by C function `malloc()` should be checked for `NULL`.

- How/why can Swift guarantee that object memory allocation will be successful, as implied by a non-optional initializer return?
- What happens if I try to instantiate a Swift object in the **minuscule but nonzero chance** that the system that is **out of memory**?

Comment: This has (briefly) been discussed in the Swift forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/allocating-memory-without-a-crash/29758

Comment: It is a reasonable question IMO.

Comment: First, don't be surprised by downvotes unaccompanied any helpful comment. It's the norm. Second, if you're really stumped by downvote, you can try posting to https://meta.stackexchange.com and you can get feedback. Third, downvote means either “does not show research effort” or “is unclear or not useful”. With no offense, this question doesn't exhibit a ton of research effort. E.g., why not write a program to manifest the problem and see what happens? Or perhaps you could have included in the question the research that you did do before posting? Just a few thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask:

> How/why can Swift guarantee that object memory allocation will be successful, as implied by a non optional initializer return?

It can't.

> What happens if I try to instantiate a Swift object in the minuscule but nonzero chance that the system that is out of memory?

Generally, it will just crash.

Fortunately, the app will often receive memory warnings before it gets to that point (at least if the app is consuming memory slowly enough for the OS to have a chance to supply a warning). So apps often have a chance to free up a little memory before everything goes south. And suspended apps may be jettisoned to free up a little memory, too.

But Swift does not gracefully handle these degenerate scenarios. We are often stuck looking at [crash reports](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/understanding-the-exception-types-in-a-crash-report), looking for [memory related crashes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/investigating-memory-access-crashes). And when we have memory issues, they often manifest in inconsistent errors (i.e., not always the same line of code), but there are tricks to [identify the source of the problem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-the-cause-of-common-crashes/). We will also often “profile” our apps periodically with Instruments to identify memory issues.

Comment: So from this it seems if the Swift allocator fails to allocate memory it will automatically abort the program.